# I am trying to create a github readme badge, but the svg image is not loading in the readme

Tags: python, github, svg

When I try to load an image from the github readme like this

`![](https://atcoder.junah.dev/v1/generate_badge?name=junah)`

it doesn't load with an error like `Error Fetching Resource`.

[image]

[image]

However, all other sites such as stackoverflow, not github, are loaded. What's the matter?

this is my lambda function code, all code is here [github repo](https://github.com/junah201/Atcoder-readme-stats)

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    username = event.get("queryStringParameters", {}).get("name", None)

    /* get data code */

    svg = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg
    width="350"
    height="170"
    viewBox="0 0 350 170"
    fill="none"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xml:space="preserve"
>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter');

        .username {{
            font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }}
        /* some css code */
    </style>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="286.703" y2="200.752" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="{darker}"/>
            <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="{darker}"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="{color}"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="350" height="170" fill="url(#gradient)" rx = "6"/>
    <g>
        /* some svg code */
    </g>
</svg>
    '''.format(
        /* some code */
    )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': svg,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=1800'
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you refresh your readme page, does it load eventually? your GitHub link readme doesn't have badge, or maybe I am looking at the wrong place.... Do you have any readme hosted with your badge?

Comment: In the readme, the image is not loaded, and like the newly added image above, if you go to the image url, it is output as `Error Fetching Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought it was a problem with my code.
However, when I loaded the image from github with a domain provided by aws, not my custom domain connected to the aws api gateway, I saw that it was displayed correctly, so I knew it was a domain problem, and I was looking for it.

I found out that sending requests with python causes ssl problems.

Ultimately the cause was no chain certificate registered in ssl.
Adding this part and adding a new certificate works fine.
Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: I reproduced your issue and was checking ssl certificate and everything seemed fine and then suddenly it started working, I thought to myself what changed and then now saw your comment that it indeed was something related to SSL. great you figured it out :)